# Spying on a constructor in javascript with sinon

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to create a spy on a constructor, and see if it gets called -- below are my tests.
I'm using sinon-chai so the syntax is valid, but both tests fail.

```
var foo = function(arg) {
};

var bar = function(arg) {
    var baz = new foo(arg);
};

it('foo initialized inside of this test', function() {
    var spy = sinon.spy(foo);
    new foo('test');
    expect(spy).to.be.called;
    expect(spy).to.be.calledWith('test');
});
it('foo initialized by bar()', function() {
    var spy = sinon.spy(foo);
    bar('test');
    expect(spy).to.be.called;
    expect(spy).to.be.calledWith('test');
});
```

Comment: Similar question + Anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338427/spying-on-date-constructor-with-sinon?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that Sinon doesn't know what reference to spy on, so the solution is to either use an object i.e. `sinon.spy(namespace, 'foo')` or override the reference yourself `foo = sinon.spy(foo)`.

Comment: A good solution should address possible class methods being called from the tested code

Answer (score 10):

Considering your constructor is bound to 'window' which means that if you open developer console on your browser, you should be able to intantiate an object by using the related function/constructor as such:

```
var temp = new FunctionName();
```

If so actual working code could be:

```
var jamesBond = sinon.spy(window, 'FunctionName');
var temp = new FunctionName(args);

expect(jamesBond.called).to.be.equal(true);
```

Comment: Thank you! Been looking for a way to do this for a long time!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use this on Node, @stckvflw's answer can be adapted assuming you know the namespace of the constructor like @billy mentioned. For JS built-in classes you'll probably be right to assume that they live in `global`.

A concrete example using `chai-spies` to freeze the `Date` object (equivalent of creating a `stub` with Sinon):

```
const moment = new Date();
chai.spy.on(global, 'Date', () => moment);
```